# Как отслеживать изменения файлов и копировать изменённые файлы в другую папку?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Суть программы: проверить файлы на последнее изменение, и если они были изменены, то копируем их в другую папку.

Так вот проблема в том, что у меня есть список файлов, полученный с помощью функции `os.listdir(path)`. Но его содержимое, всего лишь текст.

Как я могу привязать элементы к реальным файлам?

---

PS из [комментария](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538673/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83/538696#comment679339_538673):

Дата предыдущего изменения, сохраненна в списке/словаре. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы каждые 30 секунд проверялось, изменился ли файл.

Comment: Дайте пожалуйста определение: `проверить файлы на последнее изменение`. Это проверка на дату модификации файла или проверка изменения содержимого или что-то еще?

Comment: На дату модификации файла.

Comment: а что будет являться эталонной датой - время последней проверки?

Comment: Дата предыдущего изменения, сохраненного в списке/словаре. Я хочу сделать так, чтобы каждые 30 секунд проверялось, изменился ли файл.

P. S. Опыта у меня мало, изучать пайтон начал только недавно.

Comment: По-моему вам нужен модуль  [Watchdog](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/)

Answer (score 7):

Для полноты картины не хватает ответа с https://pypi.python.org/pypi/inotify

```
import logging
import inotify.adapters
_DEFAULT_LOG_FORMAT = '%(asctime)s - %(name)s - %(levelname)s - %(message)s'
_LOGGER = logging.getLogger(__name__)

def _configure_logging():
    _LOGGER.setLevel(logging.DEBUG)
    ch = logging.StreamHandler()
    formatter = logging.Formatter(_DEFAULT_LOG_FORMAT)
    ch.setFormatter(formatter)
    _LOGGER.addHandler(ch)

def _main():
    i = inotify.adapters.Inotify()
    i.add_watch('/tmp')
    try:
        for event in i.event_gen():
            if event is not None:
                (header, type_names, watch_path, filename) = event
                _LOGGER.info("WD=(%d) MASK=(%d) COOKIE=(%d) LEN=(%d) MASK->NAMES=%s "
                             "WATCH-PATH=[%s] FILENAME=[%s]",
                             header.wd, header.mask, header.cookie, header.len, type_names,
                             watch_path, filename)
    finally:
        i.remove_watch('/tmp')

if __name__ == '__main__':
    _configure_logging()
    _main()
```

`i.event_gen()` yield-ит события о изменении файлов в каталоге.

Comment: отличное решение! только жалко что работать будет только для `Linux kernel as of version 2.6`

Comment: @MaxU inotify есть и на более поздних версиях. или Вам в Виндовс?

Comment: Я скорее про Windows... Интересно а под `macOS X` это будет работать?

Comment: и под виндовс и под мак есть такие механизмы

Answer (score 3):

Вот рабочий вариант с использованием [Watchdog](https://pythonhosted.org/watchdog/api.html).

Я слегка модифицировал [этот пример](http://brunorocha.org/python/watching-a-directory-for-file-changes-with-python.html) (c) [Bruno Rocha](http://brunorocha.org/)

watch_for_changes.py:

```
from __future__ import print_function
import os
import sys
import time
import shutil
from watchdog.observers.polling import PollingObserverVFS  
from watchdog.events import PatternMatchingEventHandler 

class MyHandler(PatternMatchingEventHandler):
    #patterns = ["*.*", ".*"]

    def __init__(self, target_dir, **kwargs):
        PatternMatchingEventHandler.__init__(self, **kwargs)
        self._target_dir = target_dir

    def process(self, event):
        """
        event.event_type 
            'modified' | 'created' | 'moved' | 'deleted'
        event.is_directory
            True | False
        event.src_path
            path/to/observed/file
        """
        if not event.is_directory:
            # the file will be processed there
            print('{} {} --> {}'.format(event.src_path,
                                        event.event_type,
                                        self._target_dir))
            shutil.copy(event.src_path, self._target_dir)

    def on_modified(self, event):
        self.process(event)

    def on_created(self, event):
        self.process(event)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    args = sys.argv[1:]
    source_dir = args[0]
    target_dir = args[1]

    observer = PollingObserverVFS(stat=os.stat, listdir=os.listdir, polling_interval=30)
    observer.schedule(MyHandler(target_dir, patterns=['*.*','*','.*']),
                      path=source_dir)
    observer.start()

    try:
        while True:
            time.sleep(1)
    except KeyboardInterrupt:
        observer.stop()

    observer.join()
```

Как вызывать:

```
python watch_for_changes.py c:\source_dir c:\target_dir
```

PS в теории это должно работать на любой платформе где поддерживается Python, на практике я проверил только под Windows...

Comment: в качестве самообучения предлагаю добавить [парсинг аргументов коммандной строки](https://docs.python.org/3/library/argparse.html) - там же можно указывать сразу несколько директорий для мониторинга, задавать `polling_interval`, `patterns` и т.д. ...

Answer (score 1):

Как-то так:

```
import os
import time

for fname in os.listdir():
   t = os.path.getmtime(fname)
   print ("modification time of '{}' is {}".format(fname, time.ctime(t)))
   current_mtime[fname] = t
   if t > last_mtime[fname]:
      do_something(fname)

last_mtime = current_mtime
```

Answer (score 1):

Сидя на Linux, можно не городить костыли, а воспользоваться возможностью, предоставляемой ОС - [inotify](https://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Inotify) и специальным демоном, который облегчает работу - [incron](http://wiki.opennet.ru/Incrontab). Работает incron крайне легко и приятно. Например, строчка из incrontab файла:

```
/home    IN_CREATE             /home/user/my_cool_python_script.py $#
```

означает, что, когда в каталоге /home создан каталог или файл, будет вызван указанный скрипт с параметром, означающим имя файла, с которым произошло наблюдаемое событие.

Comment: [`watchmedo`](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/watchdog) работает и на Linux, и на macOS и на Windows

Answer (score 0):

Если к речь о файлах то можно сделать с помощь словаря:

```
import os

fdict = {}
path = "путь_к_директории_с_файлами"
files = os.listdir(path)
for i in files:
    if isfile(path+i):
        fdict[i] = open(path+i,'r')
```

Этот скрипт создаёт словарь файлов с ключами - их названиями.
Пример выбора файла из него:

```
fdict["имя_файла"]
```