# Монитор для папки

Tags: c++, python, windows, файлы

Нужно словить событие удаления(создания) файла. Первая идея, написать прогу которая циклически проверяет файлы в директории. Но мне кажется это слишком затратным по отношению к вычислительным ресурсам. Думаю, нет ли другого способа отловить события?
Или же ничего страшного не будет, если на процессор ляжет дополнительный маленький процесс? Если так, то сильно ли ударит по производительности тот факт, что прога на `python`(`java`), или лучше использовать `с++`?

Comment: [ReadDirectoryChangesW](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa365465(VS.85).aspx)

Comment: @Alexander Petrov Может, скорее  WaitForSingleObject(или WaitForSingleObjectEx) ?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538673/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83

Answer (score 0):

Нужно просто вычисление кол-ва файлов в каталоге (делать это нужно переодически, проверяя разницу между значениями). А как вычислить количество файлов, я нашел ответ на другом сайте: `http://qaru.site/`questions`/59598/how-to-count-the-number-of-files-in-a-directory-using-python`