# определить модифицирование файла с помощью watchdog on_modified события

Tags: python

скрипт ниже ищет ключевые слова из библиотеки внутри HTML-файла и записывает значения найденных ключевых слов в файле `style.css`:

```
from collections import OrderedDict
    keyword = {
    "row": '''
        .row {
        display: -ms-flexbox;
        display: flex; 
        -ms-flex-wrap: wrap;
        flex-wrap: wrap;
        margin-right: -15px;
        margin-left: -15px;
        }'''
        #etc
            }   

    with open('index.html', 'r') as file:
       with open('style.css', 'a') as newfile:
          lines = file.readlines()
          for line in lines:
             if 'class="' in line:
                to_replace = line.split('"')[1].split()
                to_replace = OrderedDict.fromkeys(to_replace)
                for key in to_replace:
                    if key in keyword:
                        newfile.write(keyword[key])
                        keyword[key] = ''
```

> **Вопрос:** Как я могу запустить скрипт каждый раз, когда файл `index.html` сохраняется И изменения совпадают определённым ключевым словам из словаря?
>   а также, как предотвратить дублирование css значений в `style.css`?

пример:

```
<div class="row">content</div>
<div class="row">content2</div>
```

нажимаю сохранить, и тогда скрипт проверяет совпадают ли значения внутри `class="` ключам из библиотеки и если совпадают, то пишет значения этих ключей в файле `style.css`. и при этом значения пишутся только один раз

совсем не понятно как использовать этот watchdоg. пока я смогла только импортировать библиотеку:

```
   from watchdog.observers import Observer
   from watchdog.events import FileSystemEventHandler
```

а что делать дальше?

Comment: Например, читать документацию watchdog?

Comment: [связанный вопрос](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538673/%D0%9A%D0%B0%D0%BA-%D0%BE%D1%82%D1%81%D0%BB%D0%B5%D0%B6%D0%B8%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B5%D0%BD%D0%B8%D1%8F-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D0%BE%D0%B2-%D0%B8-%D0%BA%D0%BE%D0%BF%D0%B8%D1%80%D0%BE%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%82%D1%8C-%D0%B8%D0%B7%D0%BC%D0%B5%D0%BD%D1%91%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B5-%D1%84%D0%B0%D0%B9%D0%BB%D1%8B-%D0%B2-%D0%B4%D1%80%D1%83%D0%B3%D1%83%D1%8E-%D0%BF%D0%B0%D0%BF%D0%BA%D1%83)