# Временный цикл в python

Tags: python, циклы

У меня есть папка, которая добавляется в результаты работы программы на диск C:/
Мне необходимо ввести цикл, чтобы наличие данной папки проверялось в течение минуты каждые 10 секунд, и, в случае, если папка была создана - цикл завершался.
Как написать данный цикл?
Понимаю, что делать нужно через 'while', но в силу того, что Python мною не изучался - не знаю как это сделать.

Comment: Можно использовать Timer из threading

Comment: По-моему, здесь лучше подойдёт [watchdog](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538696/211923)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Можно, например, так:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

import os, time


start_time = time.time()
path_to_folder = 'folder/'

while True:
    if os.path.isdir(path_to_folder):
        print "Folder found!"
        break

    if time.time()-start_time >= 60:
        print "60 seconds expired, folder not found!"
        break

    time.sleep(10)
```