# Быстрая проверка директории на наличие файлов

Tags: windows, файловая-система, windows-server

Имеем:

1. ~110 млн. файлов в директории
2. Распределение на 4 вида документов, определяемых `[typeId_числовая последовательность.расширение]`
3. Процентное распределение по `typeId` неизвестно
4. Расширения или `.xml` или `.sig`
5. Для каждого `.xml` есть аналогичный `.sig`
6. Система - windows server 2016
7. Суммарный объем директории порядка 7.5тб, занимаемых на диске
8. Xenon Silver 4116
9. 256 гб. оперативной памяти

Требуется: узнать количество документов конкретного `typeId` расширения `.xml`

Были попытки использования различных файловых менеджеров с применением регулярных выражений, но время выполнения запроса неадекватное: ~2 суток.

Попытки написание чекера файлов на kotlin / python не дали существенного прироста к поиску.

Отсюда вопрос - какой самый быстрый способ подсчитать количество такого рода документов?

***upd (29.12.19):***

Пока что самый быстрый способ - 15ч. 56м.

Финальное количество файлов `14623748`

Объем - 2.4тб.

***upd (30.12.19):***

Метод: `dir /S /B /a:-d > file_list.txt`
Скорость: ~4ч на формирование файла + парсинг файла

Comment: Есть ли возможность перевести все это на Linux? Или хотя бы раскидывать разные typeId в разные папки? 110 мил. файлов в одной директории - ненормальная ситуация.

Comment: Файлы только добавляются или удаляются тоже?

Comment: @Эникейщик Только добавляются. Но проблема добавления легче - адекватные небольшие объемы каждый день и подсчет и обработку оных можно сделать на лету. Решение этой задачи нужно для первого этапа

Comment: @MaxU вообще никак, к сожалению

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev, если система должна как-то жить и развиваться, то ее надо срочно перепроектировать. Десятки тысяч (а тем более сотни миллионов) файлов в одном каталоге это **абсолютно не работоспособно** (впрочем, если это как-то связано с "законом Яровой", то лучше не трогайте, чем скорее загнется, тем лучше)

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev - файлы часом не через сетевую шару примаунчены?

Comment: @gbg неа. Физическое хранилище в дц, куда годами копились файлы)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Основной источник проблемы - огромное количество файлов в единственной директории.

Что можно попробовать сделать, чтобы ускорить поиск:

Первое, что я попытался бы сделать - это разнести файлы по разным директориям (если это возможно). А еще лучше перенести всю эту прелесть на Linux, разнести файлы по разным директориям и использовать XFS в качестве файловой системы.

Если ничего менять нельзя, то стоит сохранять метаданные о файлах в момент создания файлов. ([Похожий пример на Python с использованием модуля `watchdog`](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538696/211923)).

Т.е. алгоритм действий примернор такой:

1. Создать базу данных (желательно на удаленном сервере, чтобы распределить IO нагрузки)
2. Создать таблицу с атрибутами файлов. Настоятельно рекомендую заранее продумать как чаще всего будет осуществляться поиск - по каким атрибутам. Скорее есть смысл парсить имя файла и хранить дополнительно `typeId`, `числовая последовательность` и `расширение` *в отдельных столбцах таблицы* для возможности наиболее эффективного и быстрого поиска. Поиск по регулярным выражениям в большинстве БД не поддерживает испольование индексов и будет работать гораздо медленнее обычного поиска по индексу.
3. Отслеживаем системные события о создании (модификации) файлов в интересующей нас директории, сохраняем метаданные, парсим дополнительные данные для поиска и сохраняем все это в SQL таблицу.
4. Далее поиск будет осуществляться по индекисрованным полям таблицы, что не должно превышать 1-3 секунд, если все сделать правильно.
5. Разумеется для *уже существующих* файлов придестя **один раз** пропарсить всю информацию, что вероятно займет около 16 часов в вашем случае.

В качестве БД я бы посоветовал использовать бесплатные [PostgreSQL](https://www.postgresql.org/about/) или [MySQL Community Edition](https://www.oracle.com/mysql/community.html) (аналог - [MariaDB](https://mariadb.org/about/)) или их платные аналоги, если позволяет бюджет.

Comment: К сожалению, данные уже на дисках, поэтому не могу понять, как можно писать метаданные ПРИ СОЗДАНИИ. Также не могу понять, зачем разносить файлы, если они уже есть, так как перенос в любом случае переберет все документы при переносе же, нет?

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev, у вас набор файлов статичный - никаких изменений не будет?

Comment: Если сделать, как советует @MaxU, у вас можно будет -параллельно делать дамп списка файлов в разных папках.
Использовать бонусы XFS в виде аснихронного доступа к метаданным, XFS листится намного быстрее NTFS

Comment: @MaxU будет дообновление, но дообновление будет уже по новой структуре и данных будет достаточно мало (в сравнении)

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev, тогда я не понимаю суть вопроса. Вы уже несколько раз (как минимум два раза) перечитали все данные о файлах - сохраните метаданные и ищите по сохраненным метаданным. Можете уточнить суть вопроса?

Comment: @MaxU таких директорий ни одна, и ни две. В этом и вопрос заключался. Разово или с одной директорией - можно было бы и подождать раз/два эти 16ч, но таких директорий, где надо выполни операцию - сотни

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev, у вас есть общая директория в которой находятся остальные "сотни" директорий? Вы пробовали запустить `dir /S /B /a:-d > file_list.txt` ? Сколько времени понадобиться для этого? Распарсить такой файл очень легко...

Comment: @MaxU Нет, не пробовал. Чуть позже запущу, проверю, сколько времени займет. Эти сотни директорий раскиданы по трем "общим" директориям

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev, еще я бы попробовал запустить `dir /S /B /a:-d > file_list.txt` __параллельно__ в нескольких директориях - может Windows позволяет делать такие операции параллельно - надо проверять...

Comment: Способ с записью списка в файл - порядка 4 часов. Уже намнооого лучше, попытаюсь еще завтра реализовать метод @AseN, сравним

Answer (score 1):

```
import os

path = r"путь/к/папке"    
total = 0
typeID = "blabla"
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.startswith(typeID) and file.endswith(".xml"):
        total = total + 1
print(total)
```

На папке в 110 тысяч файлов работает меньше 0,1 секунды.

Если гарантировано, что на каждый xml всегда есть sig, то можно расширение не проверять, а конечный результат потом разделить на 2

```
for file in os.listdir(path):
    if file.startswith(typeID):
        total = total + 1
print(total >> 1)
```

Upd. Проверил на 600 тыщ файлов: 0,40-0,45 сек.

Comment: Мне лень проверять, но что если взять os.scandir?

Comment: @andreymal Проверил. На 600к получается чуток медленее (на 4-8 сотых секунды, т.е. 10-15%). А glob.glob так и вообще в три раза медленнее.

Comment: Выполняется уже 7 часов, все еще не подсчиталось

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev Хм, это долго. Может быть, имеет смысл спросить на Super User SE.

Comment: @Эникейщик Вашим способом заняло 15ч:56м. По итогу получилось `14623748` файлов.  Хочу через день (когда станет возможным) объявить конкурс на вопрос, может так побольше людей вовлечется)

Comment: Насколько часто нужно проводить такую операцию?

Comment: Не очень часто - раз 10-15 в 2-3/мес

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev, у вас есть бэкап всех этих файлов на территориально другой площадке?

Comment: @avp К сожалению, нет...

Answer (score 1):

Поверхностная рекомендация.

Попробуйте спуститься на уровень ниже файловой системы - желательно вообще выйти и за пределы ОС - там где нет системных прерываний и соответствующих издержек. Если кусками загружать в ОЗУ raw-фрагменты HDD (пока не известно, в каком виде у вас эти 8 тб) и парсить `typeId`, уже будет существенный прирост скорости.

Можно пойти дальше, уточнив, что за файловую систему вы используете, выяснить, как в ней представлена мета-информация о файлах, вытянуть её (в теории несколько десятков мегабайт) и пройтись по сущностям.

Comment: Что значит "не известно, в каком виде у вас эти 8тб."? Как я могу уточнить этот вопрос? Точнее, в каком формате на него правильно ответить? Файловая система - NTFS. Обычное размещение на HDD на сервере

Comment: Есть распределенные ФС, в которых обработать весь массив файлов в единственном месте проблематично. В случае с NTFS известен формата мета-данных  - https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/NTFS#Metafiles, также существуют утилиты для работы с ней - https://github.com/Dijji/FileMeta

Comment: Извиняюсь, возможно, за некорректный вопрос, но существующий raid на сервере на это не влияет?

Comment: Над raid`ом абстракция в виде NTFS, потери по скорости будут зависеть от raid-контроллера. Не хочу соврать, но при таком сценарии просадка должна быть минимальной. В любом случае, к raw-виду хранилища доступ будет. Посмотрите в сторону этого инструмента - https://tzworks.net/prototype_page.php?proto_id=12

Comment: @VladimirAfanasyev увы, наличие ФС портит все удовольствие тем, что перебирать файлы удается только один-за-одним - распараллелить чтение не удается. Так что быстрее всего, действительно, снять теневую копию с MFT и распарсить. Скорость будет - несколько десятков секнуд.

Answer (score 1):

Рекомендую попробовать через **PowerShell** выполнить следующие команды.

Получение списка файлов:

```
$typeID=1337
ls $typeID*.xml > files.txt
```

Если нужны определенные свойства, например, название и размер:

```
ls $typeID*.xml | ft -Property Name, Length > files.txt
```

Непосредственно для подсчёта количества файлов:

```
(ls $typeID*.xml).Count
```

***PowerShell*** достаточно хорошо оптимизирован и встроен в систему, поэтому данные команды должны выполняться быстро.

Answer (score 0):

Имеем: директорию `./source` со 110+ миллионов файлов.

1. Создаём директорию `./sorted`
2. Пишем скрипт который проходится по `./source` и перемещает файлы оттуда в под-директории `./sorted/{typeId}`
3. Запускаем первый раз и долго ждём. Получаем `./sorted` с примерно 28 миллионов папок.
4. Вешаем этот же скрипт на крон выполняться например раз в минуту.
5. После этого ищем гораздо быстрее проверяя наличие директории `./sorted/{typeId}` (На питоне: `os.path.exists('./sorted/{typeId}')`) и если нужно перебирая и считая файлы только в этой директории, а если не найдено перебираем файлы в папке `./source` где их должно быть мало так как там будут только новые за последнюю минуту (*если скрипт по крону работает*). Должно искаться за миллисекунды.

Answer (score -2):

А я вот предлагаю зайти с другой стороны. 110 млн файлов в папке - это может и не очень нормально, но радикальных проблем создавать не должно. Вся операция заключается в тривиальном пробегании по таблице файлов, что даже с наивной реализацией посредством `FindFirstFile` / `FindNextFile` должна обрабатывать порядка миллионов файлов в секунду (а если заблаговременно проиндексировать, то операция будет моментальная). Если ваш сервер так на ней залипает, то с ним что-то не в порядке. Так что вам явно стоит проверить диски на предмет здоровья, а саму систему - на наличие проблемного ПО (антивирусы, фильтры ФС, прочие зловреды).