# Распределение файлов сразу после скачивания

Tags: python, python-3.x, файлы

Написал код, который при запуске распределяет файлы в папке Downloads по категориям. Хотел бы сделать так, чтобы файл перемещался сразу в папку подходящей категории в момент скачивания, а не после запуска скрипта.
Один из вариантов, чтоб скрипт запускался с какой-то периодичностью, но так он много времени будет работать в холостую. Подскажите, как можно это сделать рациональнее?

```
import os

os.chdir('ПУТЬ')

def repath():
    names = os.listdir()
    for name in names:
        path = os.path.abspath(name).split('\\')[-1]
        print(f'Имя файла - {path}')
        if os.path.isfile(path):
            base_name = os.path.basename(name).split('.')[-1]
            print(base_name)
            if base_name == 'png':
                img_path = 'ПУТЬ'
                os.replace(os.path.abspath(name), img_path+path)
            elif base_name == 'exe':
                exe_path = 'ПУТЬ'
                os.replace(os.path.abspath(name), exe_path+path)
            elif base_name == 'zip':
                arc_path = 'ПУТЬ'
                os.replace(os.path.abspath(name), arc_path+path)
            else:
                other_path = 'ПУТЬ'
                os.replace(os.path.abspath(name), other_path+path)




if __name__ == '__main__':
    repath()
```

Answer (score 0):

Для периодического запуска можно использовать планировщик заданий, в Windows это может быть стандартная служба - `Планировщик заданий`, для Linux - `cron` и иже с ним.

К тому же, учитывая характер задачи, стоит узнать - не поддерживает ли программа осуществляющая закачку запуск программ по завершению, что может быть одним из устраивающих вариантов.

Comment: По планировщику понял, а скчавание банальное, захотел скачать песню к примеру, в хроме нажал скачал, песня попала в общую папку и в этот момент срабатывает скрипт.

Comment: возможно поможет этот ответ https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538696/234134, да и скрипт можно как службу установить

Comment: @Banki Браузер может и не поддерживает запуск программ после скачивания, это надо проверять, но многие менеджеры закачек это умеют.