# Мониторинг наличия файла Excel и сравнение содержимого с БД

Tags: python

Как сделать что бы питон мониторил папку (например раз в 10сек) на наличие excel файла, сравнивал содержимое с бд MSSQL и выгружал обратно? Для соединения я использую pyodbc, какие еще модули мне нужны?

Comment: https://ru.stackoverflow.com/q/538673/211923

Comment: Возможный дубликат вопроса: [Как отслеживать изменения файлов и копировать изменённые файлы в другую папку?](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/538673/%d0%9a%d0%b0%d0%ba-%d0%be%d1%82%d1%81%d0%bb%d0%b5%d0%b6%d0%b8%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b5%d0%bd%d0%b8%d1%8f-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d0%be%d0%b2-%d0%b8-%d0%ba%d0%be%d0%bf%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d1%82%d1%8c-%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%bc%d0%b5%d0%bd%d1%91%d0%bd%d0%bd%d1%8b%d0%b5-%d1%84%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bb%d1%8b-%d0%b2-%d0%b4%d1%80%d1%83%d0%b3%d1%83%d1%8e-%d0%bf%d0%b0%d0%bf%d0%ba%d1%83)

Answer (score 0):

я сам новичок, но собрал вот такой код для мониторинга папки на наличие эксель файла. Именно этот код каждые 10 сек мониторит указанную папку и выводит список всех эксель файлов:

```
import os
from time import sleep

dir_name = "C:/Py/Stackoverflow"

test = os.listdir(dir_name)

while True:
    sleep(10)
    for item in test:
        if item.endswith(".xlsx") or item.endswith(".xls"):
            print (item)
```

Осталось понять что за обработку должен запускать скрипт.

Answer (score 0):

Ну можно имортировать в скрипт 'import os'. И в итоге получиться что то такое

```
import os
print(os.system('dir')) #windows
print(os.system('ls')) #linux
```

Дальше просто ищеш индекс .'разширение нужного файла' Если индекс больше нуля то файл есть.
С названием будет проще))