# я нашёл этот код но я не понимаю как его запустить --> https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538696/447539

Tags: python

https://ru.stackoverflow.com/a/538696/447539
я ввожу python watch_for_changes.py c:\source_dir c:\target_dir а оно выдаёт [image: .]

Comment: а что должно выдавать?

Comment: он должен следить за действиями в паке и выдавать какие изменения там происходят (создание, удаление)

Comment: А просто python что выдает?

Comment: если  я пытаюсь запустить из командной строки  то ничего ,а если запускаю в pycharm то
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "C:/Users/Pacific/Desktop/1/v1/67.py", line 42, in <module>
    source_dir = args[0]
IndexError: list index out of range

Comment: самое простое решение которое я вижу это если кто-нибудь объяснит мне куда и как я могу вставить в код путь  к папке

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Вы вводите команду

```
python watch_for_changes.py c:\source_dir c:\target_dir
```

Что она выполняет?

С помощью `python` в консоли вы запускаете файл под названием `watch_for_changes.py` и передаёте два строковых параметра, которые являются путями, нужными для вашей программы. Первый путь `c:\source_dir` - куда копирует файлы, `c:\target_dir` - откуда копирует файлы.

Если эта программа подходит вам, то нужно просто переписать её и подставить свои пути. Соответственно, правильно запустить и тд.

Пустота в вашей консоли символизирует либо отсутствие данного файла у вас, либо неправильный его запуск, либо еще там что. Что выдает PyCharm разбираться нужно, до этого мои руки, к сожалению, не дошли.